# Angular Display Image from Other Source

Tags: angular

Application contains 2 projects:

1. Angular UI (http://localhost:4200) upload image files to Backend
2. Backend API (nodejs, http://localhost:3000) using formidable as below:

`const IncomingForm = require('formidable').IncomingForm;`

`var ImgFolder = new IncomingForm({ uploadDir: 'C:\\Users\\me\\AllUploads' }); // corresponding to 'http://localhost:3000/uploads'`

All images uploaded are renamed by formidable to be like `upload_0d4e65f99f05e7ed14320890b75e20ae` (no extension).

How would I display an uploaded image in the Angular UI? This doesn't work

```
<img src="http://localhost:3000/uploads/upload_0d4e65f99f05e7ed14320890b75e20ae"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use proxy in your client app.

Example from Angular my project :

```
{
  "context": [ "/images" ], 
  "target" : "http://localhost:5000", 
  "secure": false, 
  "changeOrigin": true, 
  "logLevel": "debug"
}
```

With this json proxy configuration I can get files from images directory through `http://localhost:4200/images` path.

Comment: Where to set the proxy and name of the section?

Comment: [Some help](https://betterprogramming.pub/setup-a-proxy-for-api-calls-for-your-angular-cli-app-6566c02a8c4d)